# Gpio Linux conventions and names

Tags: linux, gpio

How can we find the naming of available gpios in an arbitrary board that runs Linux and then to use the Linux commands `echo "gpionumber" >/sys/class/gpio` so then we can control this gpio?

Answer (score 0):

Gpio and gpiocontrollers are numbered. Gpiocontrollers may have labels, but they may not be unique.

The linux kernel documentation on gpio sysfs driver can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt) and is a good read.

The linux kernel uses [device tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_tree) file to know which gpiocontrollers are available to him. A gpiocontroller may have multiple gpios. Each board has it's own unique device tree compiled with the kernel or loaded at boot time.

Gpiocontrollers are identified by the register and register length they refer too, see [here](https://github.com/digi-embedded/linux/blob/v4.9/dey-2.2/maint/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/fsl-imx-gpio.txt). You can specify the label of the gpiocontroller as described in [device tree file format](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dtc/dtc.git/plain/Documentation/dts-format.txt?id=HEAD) and you can query the gpiocontroller label using `/sys/class/gpio/gpiochipN/label`, they may be not unique and they don't let you identify the gpio. Also, they may change between device tree file versions.

There is no "naming", just numbering. You can query all gpios available  on a particular board by just inspecting/adding the `/sys/class/gpio/gpiochip*/ngpio` Usually a board manufacturer/provider/seller/etc provides documentation with the kernel it ships with the board with explanation, which gpio has which number/address, like for [Colibri VF61](https://docs.toradex.com/101355-colibri-vf61-datasheet.pdf). For some popular boards it is just a matter of googling to find nice looking images with gpio numbers, like for [RaspberryPi3](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Layout-Model-B-Plus-rotated-2700x900.png) or

Comment: Thanks a lot I’m going to read your links to better understanding.